# Adding a sub menu item on the sub menu

Tags: java, submenu

I would like to add an item on my sub menu on Java
Well, I have a file on the menu bar then under file is new now,
 I would like to add customer and product as the sub menu item of new
My problem is 
I don't have any idea how?
Or what is the code to use?
Can you help me pls..

Comment: create multiple `JMenu` and make a add chain like this: 
menu2.add(menu4)
menu2.add(menu3)
menu1.add(menu2)
menubar.add(menu1)

Comment: I haven't try anything